# Duplicate dates on x axis

Tags: javascript, php, graph, d3.js, nvd3.js

I created the attached function to remove the gaps and stop interpolation:

```
public static function fixDates($data) {
    $values = $data['values'];
    $fixed = [
        $values[0]
    ];

    $t1 = new \DateTime();
    $t2 = new \DateTime();

    for ($i = 1, $len = count($values); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $t1->setTimestamp(($values[$i-1]['x']/1000) + 86400);
        $t2->setTimestamp($values[$i]['x']/1000);

        $interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
        $daterange = new \DatePeriod($t1, $interval, $t2);

        foreach ($daterange as $date) {
            $fixed[] = ['x' => $date->getTimestamp() * 1000, 'y' => 0];
        }

        $fixed[] = [
            'x' => $t2->getTimestamp()*1000,
            'y' => $values[$i]['y']
        ];
    }

    $data['values'] = $fixed;
    return $data;
}
```

It produces an output array (included with the nvd3 code) like so:

```
        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
            chart.yAxis.axisLabelDistance(35);

            chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel('Time')
                .tickFormat(function (d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%d %b')(new Date(d));
                });

            chart.yAxis.axisLabelDistance(35);

            chart.yAxis
                .axisLabel('# of devices')
                .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

            d3.select('#number_of_devices svg')
                .datum([{
                    "key": "Applications",
                    "values": [{
                        "x": 1391155200000,
                        "y": 5
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391241600000,
                        "y": 0
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391328000000,
                        "y": 0
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391414400000,
                        "y": 6
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391500800000,
                        "y": 0
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391587200000,
                        "y": 0
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391673600000,
                        "y": 0
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391760000000,
                        "y": 0
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391846400000,
                        "y": 31
                    }, {
                        "x": 1391932800000,
                        "y": 8
                    }]
                }])
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });
```

This is working great, however, I have duplicate days showing up on the x axis, as shown in this picture: http://shutter.io/img/lvith8/raw

Any ideas what i'm missing?

**Edit:**

It's unrelated to this dataset and only happens because it's a large graph width and low amount of datapoints. If I reduce the width of the graph and force it to update it fixes itself, but I'd still like it to work as expected at any width.

I thought my tickFormatter ( `return d3.time.format('%d %b')(new Date(d));` ) would compensate for that.

Comment: The tick formatter just tells it how to format the ticks, it won't do any filtering. To control how many and what ticks appear, use [`.ticks()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks) and [`.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues).

Comment: Can you provide sample of applying that with the above dataset? Given its a set of dynamic dates I can't supply a static set of tick values - is d3 able to calculate it?

Comment: Well yes, it does calculate it -- the documentation I've linked to has examples that allow you to specify e.g. one tick per month.

Comment: This fixed for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/22267524/355507

Comment: It bite me again today! .tickValues() is the way to go!